# How to save default UIPicker value when user doesn't pick any value

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a set of pickers, each of which have a pre-selected value such as this code shows where 150 lbs is the pre-selected value:

```
arrayPickerWeight = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
for ( int i = 80 ; i <= 360 ; i+=10 ) {
    [arrayPickerWeight addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
}   

// Calculate the screen's width.
float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
float pickerWidth = screenWidth * 3 / 4;
// Calculate the starting x coordinate.
float xPoint = screenWidth / 2 - pickerWidth / 2;
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
// Set the delegate and datasource. 
[pickerView setDataSource: self];
[pickerView setDelegate:   self];
// Set the picker's frame to 50px.
[pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(xPoint, 50.0f, pickerWidth, 180.0f)];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
// Set the default value to be displayed
[pickerView selectRow:7 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview: pickerView];
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

Everything works fine if the user picks a value. This method gets called as expected:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    message = [arrayPickerWeight objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

However, if they just click the save button without moving the picker, I get null in my message field. So I hand-coded this code to set it to kDefaultPickerWeight, which is 150 lbs.

```
//if picker value is null then populate with default shown    
if ([message length] == 0)
{
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",kDefaultPickerWeight];
}
```

However, is there something I'm missing or something I need to do to get the 150 lbs automatically stored in my message variable or do i have to hand-code the value like I did?

Thanks

Comment: have tried `if (message == nil){...}`?

Comment: I think that's effectively what I'm doing with checking the message length. I was just wondering if there is a way to get the pre-selected value stored into the receiving variable without have to check if it is null, in terms of the natural behavior or methods associated with UIPicker. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would use NSUserDefaults. If picker value hasn't been changed, or even when the picker is appeared for the first time, you can read from NSUserDefaults. You can also save user's input in NSUserDefaults.

If the app is running for the very first time, you can have a method in your app delegate to set the NSUserDefaults to a predeifned value.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks Canopus - I'll look into NSUserDefaults. I haven't considered that approach. I like being able to save what they chose last time as a NSDefault as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you:

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

You can call this method to figure out which row is currently selected and there does not have to be any user interaction with the picker first. So if you want to find out the selected row when you first launch the view that's what you would use.

Example:

```
int row = [picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSLog(@"Selected row = %i", row);
```